# Volume via double integral - dividing the section for positive $z$ and negative $z$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

so my textbook gave the following exercise:

Calculate the volume of the area which is bounded by the following surfaces: $x=1$, $x=3$, $y=1$, $y=5$, $z=0$, $z=4-2x$

As a hint, they told us that we had to divide the section into two parts, the first one where $z>0$ and the second one where $z<0$.

This is my approach so please tell me if I am correct or incorrect, and I'd appreciate if someone would provide help if I am incorrect

I evaluated the following integrals:

$$ \int_{1}^{5} \int_{1}^{3} |4-2x|dxdy$$

$|4-2x| = 4-2x$ for $x \le 2$

$|4-2x| = 2x-4$ for $x > 2$

Which amounts to:

$$ \int_{1}^{5} \int_{1}^{2}(4-2x)dxdy + \int_{1}^{5} \int_{2}^{3} (2x-4)dxdy$$

Both integrals evaluate to 4, so the sum is $8$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Andrei Thanks! The reason I'm asking is because I have never come across this kind of problem, it may seem trivial but this is my first exercise!

Comment: @johndoe nicely done!

Comment: @MathLover Thanks very much!